# SQL Case With Many Columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join, case

Hi I have looked through the "Case with multiple columns" questions and don't see something the same as this so I think I should ask.

Basically I have two tables (both are the result of a subquery) which I want to join. They have the same column names. If I join them on their ids and `SELECT *` I get each row being something like this:

`A.id, A.x, A.y, A.z, A.num, B.id, B.x, B.y, B.z, B.num`

What I want is a way to only select the columns of the table with the lower value of num. So in this case the result table would always have 5 columns, `id, x, y, z, num`, and I don't care which table `id, x, y, z, num` came from after the fact. Also either table result is fine if they are equal.

`SELECT CASE WHEN A.num < B.num THEN A.* ELSE B.* END FROM A JOIN B ON A.id=B.id`

would be perfect but you can only return one column in a CASE statement, and I could use a CASE for every column but that seems so wasteful (there are 8 in each table in my actual database so I would have 8 CASE statements).

This is SQLite btw. Any help would be appreciated!

---

**Edit for more info on A and B:**
A and B come from Queries like this

SELECT "thought case statement might go here" FROM

(SELECT id, x, y, z, num FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b ON a.id=b.id AND (y BETWEEN (53348574-3593) AND (53348574+3593)) AND (z BETWEEN (-6259973-6027) AND (-6259973+6027)) JOIN Table3 c ON c.id= b.id GROUP BY a.id, c.r) A

JOIN

(SELECT id, x, y, z, num FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b ON a.id=b.id AND (y BETWEEN (53401007-3593) AND (53401007+3593)) AND (z BETWEEN (-6397286-6027) AND (-6397286+6027)) JOIN Table3 c ON c.id= b.id GROUP BY a.id, c.r ) B ON A.id=B.id

So it joins two tables, made based on geolocation if you're wondering why the big numbers, and needs to decide which of the tables to take its data from based on attributes of what it finds in either of the locations.

Comment: @Tichodroma http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg09.htm

Comment: @Tichodroma It does support CASE, it is not on that page because CASE is an expression. See here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any RDBMS supporting what you want. You will have to write 8 CASE statements. But why is it so wasteful? <s>Or are you just lazy? :)</s>

Edit:

See, when you write `SELECT * ...` what your RDBMS is doing is to query system tables (information_schema and so on) and get the list of columns in the table.
So when you write

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.num < B.num THEN A.* ELSE B.* END ...
```

you basically write

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.num < B.num THEN A.num, A.whatever, A.more, ... ELSE B.num, B.whatever, B.more... END FROM A JOIN B ON A.id=B.id
```

and this is unfortunately wrong syntax.

Comment: I think it's wasteful because it would mean 8 Case expressions are evaluated all the time instead of 1 :p It also looks bad and doesn't seem great for maintainability.

Comment: Even if your `*` thing would work, all 8 are evaluated. Just because you write one, does not mean there is just one.

Comment: Didn't know enter sends the comment so bear with me while I edit...

So 

SELECT CASE WHEN A.num < B.num THEN A.id ELSE B.id END, CASE WHEN A.num < B.num THEN A.x ELSE B.x END, CASE WHEN A.num < B.num THEN A.y ELSE B.y END, ... FROM ...

Would be the same? It seems so wrong to evaluate the same if condition so many times :s

Comment: @herojan Updated my answer. I'm sorry, there's really no way around this. At least none, that wouldn't be much uglier than those 8 CASEs.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I knew the case statement only takes one column which was the problem. But the same case statement for each column I want to add just seems so weird. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select A.id, A.x, A.y, A.z, A.num from  A JOIN B ON A.id=B.id where a.num<b.num
union
select b.id, b.x, b.y, b.z, b.num from  A JOIN B ON A.id=B.id where b.num<a.numhere
```

Comment: But I would have to do the sub-queries again in this case wouldn't I? (A and B come from sub-queries, and I called the result tables A and B). I tried it in SQLite database browser and it doesn't know what the A is after the UNION, it seems to only exist in the SELECT statement it was created in.

Comment: well in that case plz post your whole query. then only we get a clear idea what you are trying to achieve.